# Downloading a video file using AFNetworking for iOS app

Tags: ios, afnetworking, dropbox, mp4

I'm a complete newbie to xcode development. However im doing it for a uni project.
I need to download a video from Dropbox which i've uploaded onto my account.

I managed to stream it with the help of a previous question. However i can't seem to download the video. I can in the other hand download zip files etc. Is my URL just wrong and not possible to download from DropBox?
For downloading I'm using AFNetworking

```
  -(IBAction)download{
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc]  initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0c163kau6u2smyd/HXH2011_1.mp4"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
        return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[targetPath lastPathComponent]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
            }
```

http://example.com/download.zip works fine

I have also tried https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/0c163kau6u2smyd/HXH2011_1.mp4?=dl

Comment: You said "I can't seem to download the video." Does that mean you got an error of some sort? If so, what is the error?

Comment: theres no error messages coming up in my debugging. nor is their any at all. Just plain white...

Comment: What do you mean "white"? How do you know the download is failing?

Comment: like its empty in the NSLOG, if the download works, it should be downloaded into the temp file of the simulation and there will be a message.

Comment: So your `completionHandler` is never invoked? Or it's invoked but with an `error` parameter?

Comment: its not invoked. However when using different urls it is always invoked